# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'diagnostic' of undefined in cordovo app

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap, html-framework-7

my application's geolocation was working with sign in mode..
but gives error like

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'diagnostic' of undefined
>       at on ErrorPo** without sign in option..

how to solve this issue....
may be JavaScript problem..

sign in mode javascript:

```js
$$(document).on('pageAfterAnimation', '.page[data-page="zone"]', function (e) {
  var page = e.detail.page;
  window.back_page = 'section.html?id='+page.query.cat;
  if (page.query.back_page)
    window.back_page = page.query.back_page;
  myApp.showPreloader(trans('جاري تحديث الموقع... تأكد من تفعيل خدمة الـ GPS'));
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
    window.xpos = position.coords.latitude;
    window.ypos = position.coords.longitude;
    updatePosition(function(data) {
      myApp.hidePreloader();
      myApp.hidePreloader();
      loadZone(page);
    });
  }, function(){
    myApp.hidePreloader();
    myApp.hidePreloader();
    myApp.alert(trans('من فضلك تأكد من تفعيل خدمة الـ GPS', trans('خطأ')));
    console.log('error getting position in zone');
    loadZone(page);
  }, { maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
});
```

without sign in javascript:

```js
$$(document).on('pageAfterAnimation', '.page[data-page="area1"]', function (e)
 {
  var page = e.detail.page;
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccessPos, onErrorPos, { maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
 

  myApp.showPreloader(trans('جاري تحديث الموقع... تأكد من تفعيل خدمة الـ GPS'));
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
    window.xpos = position.coords.latitude;
    window.ypos = position.coords.longitude;
     
     
      loadzone(page);
    
  }, function(){
  
    myApp.alert(trans('من فضلك تأكد من تفعيل خدمة الـ GPS', trans('خطأ')));
    console.log('error getting position in zone');
   
  }, { maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
});
```

Comment: Why do you have this `$$(document)` instead of this `$(document)`?

Comment: Is your code in the device ready event? It seems like your plugin is not loaded.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze    yes     $$(document).on('deviceready', function deviceIsReady() {
  console.log('Device is ready!');
  runStaffDelayRequests();
  StatusBar.show();
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}); how to solve plugin issue...